# Wiring vent fan and light as well as LED puck lights off of 14/3 cable

Tags: electrical

I’m taking out an old bathroom vent fan with a light that’s run off of two separate switches using 14/3 wire I want to wire the new vent and light onto one switch while I use the other switch to run new LED puck lights.

The LED puck lights are going to be on a dimmer switch while the vent and light combo are going to be on a standard switch.

My question is, is it possible to run a dimmer switch on a 14/3 line with a standard switch on the same line?

Or should I just pull out the old 14/3 wire and wire both fixtures separately with 14/2?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace one switch with a dimmer, operate both parts parts of the fan/light combo with the other switch and use the dimmer for a new light.
This will work fine with the existing 14/3 cable.

In the switch box, leave the black wire on one switch and connect the red wire to the new dimmer. At the fan, connect the black to both of the fan and fan-light hot wires. Connect the red wire to your new light. Assuming you need to move the new light away, extend the red, white and ground to the light using 14/2 cable.

Comment: For clarity, it is 100% OK to connect the red of the 14/3 cable to the black of the 14/2 cable in order to extend the switched hot to the new lights.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, that is exactly what you should do.